# Receiving an Ajax error on an insert of a record

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC 5.2 for an ASP.Net Ajax call, and am receiving the below error message:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Note that all I'm doing is **inserting** a record into a table. The database gets updated successfully, but I still receive that error message.

I understand what the error *means* where it's expecting json data coming back in the call, but it's simply an **insert** and **not** a **select** (where data would be expected to come back).

Below, is the screen shot that explains my whole situation.

Can someone please inform me how to fix this? I shouldn't be getting that error message if I'm just inserting a record...

[image]

Comment: I think your content type is wrong. it should be html if your server is returning html. In MVC you are returning a View which is parsed by razor engine to output html.  if you want json then in your action method you have to return jsonresult.

Comment: You need to include the code!

Comment: meetkichu was correct. thanks.. the contentType I am sending is the default, not json; and the datatype I am getting back should be html; not json since I am simply inserting data. Thanks.